# Adobe flash player is not clearing recorded data in IE

Tags: axshockwaveflash

Steps to reproduce:
note : (application type as `application/x-shockwave-flash`)

1. Click on `start recording`, record your recordings and attach the file (now recording player div is closed)
2. Now again click on `start recording` (now you can able to see the previous recorded data in player div),

**Reproducible only in IE, not on other browsers.**